# Is there a way to have 1 button do something in a different form

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble with vb i want one button to add an items to a list box in a different form. I am trying to make it so that a user can enter in a value(money) into text box and then that value is saved in the list box in a different form which then shows them how much money they have spent in a certain category. I have been able to to make this work by using the public class but every time you enter in a number you have to go to the second form and click show for it to hold the value which isn't really the best. I have tried to make the update button in the first form add the items into the list box but i cant seem to make it work as it i cannot be converted to integer or string. I am new to vb just want to know if there is a way so that i don't have to go to the second form every time.

**This is the code that is working but i have to go to the second form every time i enter in the amount of money spent on an item. **

*First form*

```
Public Class frm1MainScreen
    Friend strName As Integer

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click, 

    strName = txtAdvertising.Text
```

*Second Form*

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
    lstMoney.Text = lstMoney.Items.Add("$" & frm1MainScreen.strName)
    txtAdvertising.Text = Val(txtAdvertising.Text) + Val(frm1MainScreen.strName)

End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to add the code you are using to the question.

Comment: The fact that you have no badges indicates that you rejected the prompt to take the site tour when you registered. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works so that we don't have to instruct you on how to write a proper question each time.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want something to happen in a form then that form should be doing it. If you want to add items to a `ListBox` then write a method in its own form to do that. Make that method `Public` and then have the first form call that method. If the first form has to provide the items then add a parameter to the method and the first form then passes the items as an argument when calling it. This assumes that the first form is creating the form with the `ListBox` in the first place. If it's the other way around, things change. We don't know if we can't see your code.

Comment: Get rid of the `Button` on the second form and write a method with the same code but use a parameter for the text rather than `frm1MainScreen.strName`. In the first form, call that method on the second form and pass the value as an argument instead of assigning it to a field.